# List followed groups and sites in SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, fetch, es6-promise

#### The issue: Retrieving a list of followed sharepoint groups and sites

I'm trying to retrieve a list (or similar) that will include all sharepoint sites and groups that the current user is following. This is to be used in an SPFx webpart.

I also need to retrieve `groupId`, not only the `webId`or `listId`.

The MS Graph **beta** provides an endpoint - `me/followedSites` - for listing all followed sites, but this doesn't necessarily include all groups, and definitely won't include the `groupId`.

Answer (score 1):

(I found the solution, so I'm just gonna leave it here for others to find...)

#### The solution: Use the SharePoint Home api

Use the SharePoint Home API to retrieve fresh tokens and urls, then make another request to the returned url with the new tokens.

I put together this little function to help achieve that:

```
// An instantiated object from the WebPartContext is required
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

// Retrieve a list of followed sites and groups
function FetchFollowed(context: WebPartContext): Promise<any[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fetch(
      `${context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/sphomeservice/context?$expand=Token,Payload`,
      { headers: { accept: "application/json" } }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({ Urls, Token, Payload }) =>
        fetch(
          `${Urls[0]}/api/v1/sites/followed?expand=ItemReference&fillSiteData=true`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${Token.access_token}`,
              "sphome-apicontext": Payload
            }
          }
        )
          .then(result => result.json())
          .then(result => resolve(result.Items))
          .catch(reject)
      )
      .catch(reject)
  );
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. Do you know if there's some documentation how to use the sites api? Or do you know how to filter on certain ItemReference attributes?